# Can I Install Visual C++ Redistributable 2010 and/or DirectX 10 to a Particular Folder?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, directx-10

I am looking to create a portable version of a program for Windows 8 that requires VCRedist 2010 and DirectX 10 to run properly. However, I am unable to use the installers because they attempt to install to the system path and, while the computer I am working on has administrator rights, I do not have it on the computers I will be transferring it to. After a lot of research, It seems I can include the VCRedist 2010 and DirectX 10 dll files in the application folder, but I have been unable to find a list of all the required dlls. If this is true could someone provide me with a list of them, and if it's not true does anyone know of an alternative way to do this?

System info: 32 bit OS, Windows 8

Comment: You can't legally install the DirectX redistributables side-by-side with your application. They need to be installed with the installer included in the redist folder of the SDK.  You'll either have to rewrite your application so you don't use any of the redist components (D3DX, xinput, etc..) or get someone with admin privileges to do the install. I don't know the requirements for VC 2010 off hand. The rule change a fair bit between VisualStudio releases. Note that DirectX 10 itself isn't part of the redist package, it's included in the OS (Vista or later).

Answer (score 2):

The first thing to say here is that you never redistribute DirectX. It is part of the operating system and can only be updated by a service pack, upgrading the OS, or through Windows Update. That has been true since Windows XP Service Pack 2, but it is a poorly understood fact.

**The DirectX End-User Runtime packages (aka [DXSETUP](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/chuckw/archive/2011/04/19/dxsetup-update.aspx) and [DXWSETUP](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/chuckw/archive/2010/11/30/dxwebsetup-update.aspx)) never installs any version of DirectX on any version of the operating system!** That has been true for over a decade.

If your application makes use of one of the side-by-side optional components that ship in the legacy DirectX SDK such as D3DX9, D3DX10, D3DX11, D3DCompile #43, XAudio 2.7, XInput 1.3, or XACT, then you must use the legacy DirectSetup package to redist those DLLs as they are never part of the operating system. Using DirectSetup always requires administrator rights.

See [Not So DirectSetup](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/chuckw/archive/2010/09/08/not-so-direct-setup.aspx) for a fuller explanation.

For Windows 8 standard user only application, a better option is to use DirectX 11 and make use of one of the many [open source replacements](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/chuckw/archive/2013/08/21/living-without-d3dx.aspx) for D3DX functionality. If you need XAudio, you can use [XAudio 2.8](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/chuckw/archive/2012/04/02/xaudio2-and-windows-8-consumer-preview.aspx). If you use [D3DCompile](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/chuckw/archive/2012/04/02/xaudio2-and-windows-8-consumer-preview.aspx), you can include it side-by-side with your application from the Windows 8 SDK. If you use XInput, you can use [XInput 1.4 or the older XInput 9.1.0](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/chuckw/archive/2012/04/25/xinput-and-windows-8-consumer-preview.aspx).

> Note that Windows 8.0 is now end-of-life. While still supported as a target for Visual Studio 2015, those users are expected to upgrade to either Windows 8.1 or Windows 10 to maintain support. In Windows 8.1, the D3DCompile #47 DLL is already part of the operating system.

Visual C++ 2010, 2012, 2013, and 2015 DLLs can be included side-by-side (aka [application local deployment](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd293574.aspx)). You can use the Windows 8.1 SDK with VS 2010 using [props](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/chuckw/archive/2013/10/18/visual-studio-2013-and-windows-8-1-sdk-rtm-are-now-available.aspx) files, but I'd recommend moving to a newer version of Visual Studio which can more easily make use of Windows 8.1 SDK content.

> Another option here is to use VS 2013, target Windows 8 Store, and use that to handle all the deployment which does not require admin rights. You still have to use Direct3D 11 and avoid all use of legacy DirectX SDK components including D3DX9/D3DX10/D3DX11.

See [Where is the DirectX SDK?](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee663275.aspx).